# Cypress - Check if video is paused or not

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, cypress

I using Cypress. I have a video in my URL and I want to check if the video is in pause.

I have the follow html code:

```
<video id="mainVideo" controls="" loop="" autoplay="autoplay" playsinline="playsinline" preload="metadata" data-aos="fade-up">
    <source src="/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">Your navigator doesnt support videos.
</video>
```

I used the follow code in my test for debug:

```
cy.get('#mainVideo').debug();
```

I saw that has the follow property "paused":
[Property Paused](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWvQH.png)

But when I try to check if the is true, as a attribute, with this code, it does not find it:

```
cy.get('#mainVideo').should('have.attr', 'paused', true):
```

The result, time out:
[Result test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMO0i.png)

How I can access to that "pause" video's "property"?

**UPDATE:**
I did it with this:

```
cy.get('#mainVideo').should($video => { expect($video.get(0)).to.have.property('paused', true); });
```

Comment: `cy.get('#mainVideo').its('paused').should('eq', true)` - see [docs - its](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/its.html#Examples) for accessing properties.

Comment: This: cy.get('#mainVideo').its('paused') is undefined and not true: https://ibb.co/7WJj0th

Comment: cy.get('#mainVideo').should($video => { expect($video.get(0)).to.have.property('paused', true); });
worked for me, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Accessing the underlying `<video>` element worked for me:

```js
cy.get('video').then(([videoEl]) => {
  expect(videoEl.paused).to.equal(true);
});
```

A shorthand version of that (without the `.then(() => {}`):

```js
cy.get('video').its('0.paused').should('equal', true);
```

Because `cy.get()` returns the jQuery object, you have to first access it's `0` property before you can access any built-in DOM attributes.